# solve a system of nonlinear equations in R

Tags: r

I want to solve a system of nonlinear equations but I have stuck in R code.

```
install.packages("nleqslv")
library(nleqslv)
se_function<-function(A,b,c){
  n<-nrow(Se_data)
  k1<-Se_data$HTA.
  k2<-Se_data$RMA.
  k3<-Se_data$CMA.
  F<-Se_data$rc_mean
  Area<-Se_data$MTA
  F[n]<-A+b[1]*exp(k1[n]*Area[n]/c[1])+b[2]*exp(k2[n]*Area[n]/c[2])+b[3]*exp(k3[n]*Area[n]/c[3])
  F
}
startX<-rnorm(50)
se_result<-dfsane(startX,se_function,control = list(maxit=500,trace=FALSE))
```

The equation I want to solve:
[image]

in this equation, I have already known the x,y and k[1,2,3], and I want to know the value of A,b[1,2,3]and c[1,2,3]. There are 25 teams of x, y and k, but I have got the following messages

```
Error in fn(par, ...) : argument "b" is missing, with no default
Error in dfsane(startX, se_function, control = list(maxit = 500, trace = FALSE)) : 
  Failure in initial functional evaluation.
```

Please help me and can you explain how to use the function() ?
Thank you very much.

Comment: I suspect you want `n <-1:nrow(Se_data)`. As it currently stands you are only giving a single value to `n`, whereas the rest of your code implies you expect it to be vector of length nrow(Se_data). Then you return a vector, whereas optimization would need a cost value to optimize. (And I'm not seeing a "system". Only seeing a single equation.

Comment: You are using `dfsane` which is not from the `nleqslv` package but from another package. Please display the correct package you are using. Also where is the `y` from your formula? `F[n]` should be something like this: `F[n] <- y - (....)`. And you might not even need the `[n]`.